# How to scrub PrivateKey data from memory after using it?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, private-key

Is there a way to delete the sensitive information from a `PrivateKey` out of the memory? (Without hoping for the Garbage Collector to clean up ?)

Do I have to write my own implementation of `PrivateKey`
*or*
Is there something already that i could use?

Comment: If you don't have reference to it, why do you think you have to worry about it being in memory?

Comment: This is just to strengthen the security of an application.
When the GC doesnt run right behind removing all references to the PrivateKey it is still possible to read/dump the memory and retrieve the PrivateKey. But if I can make sure that this data is overwritten after usage this risk is minimized to a timeframe from decrypting the PrivateKey to using it. And not from decrypting it to somewhen in the future where the GC thinks its ok to clean up. ;)

Comment: To do this well is pretty hard. The GC may more or copy around your objects, it might be swapped to a SSD (from where you can't delete it), it might end up in crash dumps,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that none of the sensitive data is put into an immutable data type (e.g., you cannot use String), because when you are done with the sensitive data, you need to be able to overwrite it.

You will probably keep the meat of the private key in a byte array (since this is exactly what `getEncoded()` returns). When you are done with the private key, fill the byte array with zeros (or whatever).

You may need to implement your own version of PrivateKey, so you can add this new functionality (because you cannot guarantee that the provided implementation returns an alias to the actual array rather than a copy).

You also need to worry about any callers of `getEncoded()`, because the caller could keep a copy of the data.

Comment: Seems like I really have to implement my own PrivateKey :(
thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, but at least is is a very simple interface so it won't be too bad.

Comment: Darn, must have been sleeping. This scheme does not work. The Java implementation of Cipher and Signature will have to retrieve the private exponent, which is returned as an immutable integer. Game over, unless you also implement a `Cipher` or `Signature` securely (using a separate interface). Even then, the memory can be copied by the JVM, leaving a trace.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this within regular Java without going native. The JVM can always copy the data and the `RSAPrivateKey` interface specifies `getPrivateExponent()` to return an immutable `BitInteger` instance. This is used by the `Cipher` and `Signature` classes. Using a secure token (e.g. using the Sun PKCS#11 provider) is the best way to go.

There are serious issues by using decryption or signing in software if you don't think that the memory can be kept safe, whatever you do. You require at least operating system level support, which is not something that is enabled within Oracle Java implementations.